# Extract users from list, to a webpart SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, lync

I need to extract som information from a SharePoint list. Let us call this list for list_A. And in list_A I have column containing sharepoint users. That show their lync status (online, offline, busy etc), and when I hover over that user name I will get an "toolbox" that shows additional information. (See the picture)

[image: user]

What I now want is to extract that list of users into an SharePoint web part and have the ability to show the same information as in list_A. In other words I want to get the lync integration, with their status and the info box on hover. I figure I will manage to extract the information from the list without any problems using a method somewhat like the one below:

```
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url))
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            {
                SPList lists = web.Lists["listName"];
                foreach (SPListItem item in lists.Items)
                {
                    string test = Convert.ToString(item["columnName"]);
                    TextBox1.Text += test;

                }
            }
         }
```

But the question is if there is an asp or sharepoint controller that will allow me to show this kind field on the web page/in the web part?

Answer (score 0):

Create a LiteralControl and use the following code to display the user presence in your webpart

```
("<span><img border=\"0\" height=\"12\" src=\"/_layouts/images/imnhdr.gif\" onload=\"IMNRC('" + userEmail+ "')\" ShowOfflinePawn=\"1\" alt=\"\" id=\"user_presence_icon\"/></span>");
```

There is a forum discussion on this topic and can be refered [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/77c90823-c8fd-437a-9e31-3c312773ae3c/how-to-show-user-online-presence-in-custom-webparts-in-sharepoint-2010?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious) -

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks, this may be of help. I cant actually test it before tomorrow, but I will come back to you. It looks promising though!

Comment: Okey, so an update. This seems to be doing the trick. But as of now, the box containing extra information(picture in my question) is only showing when I hoover over the smal square that shows the presence status. Is it possbile to show it when I hover over some text (i.e. user name)? I have tried to put text inside the span with no luck. like this:
<span><img tag ... />User Name</span>